# storing values into double vector with same precision C++

Tags: c++, vector, floating-point-precision

Here is my problem. I have a vector suct that vector and after some operations I'll store some double values into this vector.However,I want they all have same decimal point digit. I mean if first value to be stored is *4.143* and the second one is *67.32* and the third one is 165 then I want to store them like *004.143* and *067.320* *165.000*.Is there any way to do that? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing how they are *stored* with how they are *displayed*.

When you display the values, you can use, for example, [`String.format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) or [System.out.printf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) to format the value to a specified width and number of decimal places.

For example:

```
double a = 4.143;
double b = 67.32;
double c = 165;
System.out.printf("%07.3f %07.3f %07.3f", a, b, c);
```

Prints:

```
004.143 067.320 165.000
```

Edit: So it's C++ (sorry; I've been answering Java questions all day). The same holds, except `printf()` or `stringstream` or `ostream` is used to format instead. The concepts are the same.

As for your comments below: "034.1" and "34.1" are the same value. They are stored the same in either language. Padding 0's are a function of display, not storage. A radix sort traditionally involves integers; you could convert your values to integers by e.g. multiplying by 1000 (or whatever), then just use math to get the digits. For example:

```
double value1 = 0.124; 
double value2 = 53.0;

printf("%i\n", (int)(value1 * 1000.0) % 10);
printf("%i\n", (int)(value2 * 1000.0) % 10);
```

Prints 4 and 0 (the thousandths digit). For your radix sort, when comparing two keys, compute and compare digits appropriately.

Comment: ,I've asked it because, I'll use these values in a radix sort.So,they need to have a same number of digits.

Comment: I'm interested in how they're stored rather than how they're displayed as I said

Comment: and sorry for missunderstanding,Its a c++ question not a java

Comment: How they are stored is how they are stored. Leading 0's are a characteristic of display, not storage. "034" and "34" are the same value and are stored the same. Also, a radix sort is generally done with integers, and you can pull out digits using math (e.g. `(value / 100) % 10`. One option for doubles is to sort by their actual value, or to format them as fixed width strings and sort alphabetically. The former makes more sense.

Comment: @caesar The answer is the same in either language, except you use `printf` or something from `sstream` or `ostream` to format. In C++ as well as Java, the stored value is unrelated to padding 0's. In both languages, what I just said about radix sort is true.

Comment: I have to sort floating points no argue that.

Comment: Ok then what's the problem with sorting by their values? 165 > 67.32 > 4.143 no matter how many padding 0's you add.

Comment: Dont I have to have same number of digits for all values to be compared in radix sort ?

Comment: Sure but just compute the digit. `(int)(doubleValue * 1000.0) % 10` will extract 4 from 0.134.

Answer (score 1):

The `float` type is named that way, because it represents a **floating** point number. If you wan't to store numbers with fixed-position, you have to design your own class for that (or use one that [someone else made](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37636/Fixed-Point-Class)). There's no other way.

But - if you're only concerned about the fact that floating point numbers are stored differently in memory, dependant on the point position, then you're wrong. No matter where the dot is, the coding is the same. You should read about the [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) standard.

You could also use a `stringstream` in order to write a `float` into a `std::string` with fixed precision.

And of course if you're just concerned about the **display**, other people already made that clear in their replies.

Comment: The OP appears to be trying to implement a radix sort and is under the impression that storage/display affects the ability to extract digits from the number. What he *should* be doing is using math to operate on the values and extract the relevant digits, instead of being concerned with storage/display.

Comment: Whatever the OP is concered about, is explained in this post, so he can pick whatever option he wants. I've already tried helping someone understand something in the correct way on this site, and it's not worth. People want precise answers. If they wanted to understand, they would learn and try, instead of immediately asking. There's no point. No matter if it's fixed or floating of convincing anyone :)